# PGFPlot vector field has uneven display

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, vector

I have a simple 2D vector, however the points are aligned such that the vectors at the top pointing upwards are not include in the plot. I was wondering if there's a way to make the vector field more evenly distributed as seen here,[image].

The image is the second axis in the pgfplot.

```
 \begin{figure}[h]
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
     ticks=none,
    view     = {0}{90},
  domain   = -1:1,
  y domain = -1:1,
  samples  = 21,
  xmax     = 1,
  ymax     = 1
]
\addplot3 [blue, quiver={u={-(x)/(x^2+y^2)}, v={-(y)/(x^2+y^2)}, scale 
arrows=0.04},samples=8,->] (x,y,0);
\draw (axis cs:0,0) node [above] {$z_0$};
\filldraw(axis cs: 0,0)circle(1pt); 

\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[ xshift=8cm,
ticks=none,
  view     = {0}{90},
  domain   = -1:1,
  y domain = -1:1,
  samples  = 21,
  xmax     = 1,
  ymax     = 1
  ]
  \draw (axis cs:1.25,1.25) circle [blue, radius=0.3];
  \addplot3 [blue, quiver={u={(x)/(x^2+y^2)}, v={(y)/(x^2+y^2)}, scale 
   arrows=0.04},samples=8,->] (x,y,0);
\draw (axis cs:0,0) node [above] {$z_0$};
\filldraw(axis cs: 0,0)circle(1pt); 

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Sink and source centred around $z_0$.}

\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from `xmax` and `ymax`, which clips the overshooting vectors away.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
     ticks=none,
    view     = {0}{90},
  domain   = -1:1,
  y domain = -1:1,
  samples  = 21,
%   xmax     = 1,
%   ymax     = 1
]
\addplot3 [blue, quiver={u={-(x)/(x^2+y^2)}, v={-(y)/(x^2+y^2)}, scale 
arrows=0.04},samples=8,->] (x,y,0);
\draw (axis cs:0,0) node [above] {$z_0$};
\filldraw(axis cs: 0,0)circle(1pt); 

\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[ xshift=8cm,
ticks=none,
  view     = {0}{90},
  domain   = -1:1,
  y domain = -1:1,
  samples  = 21,
%   xmax     = 1,
%   ymax     = 1,
  ]
  %\draw (axis cs:1.25,1.25) circle [blue, radius=0.3];

  \addplot3 [blue, quiver={u={(x)/(x^2+y^2)}, v={(y)/(x^2+y^2)}, scale 
   arrows=0.04},samples=8,->] (x,y,0);
\draw (axis cs:0,0) node [above] {$z_0$};
\filldraw(axis cs: 0,0)circle(1pt); 

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing something similar to that, thanks for trying its a shame there's not a proper way of 'windowing' the vector field so that they're equally distributed.

Comment: @JohnMiller Actually I found a much more elegant (IMHO) proposal. The issue is that you specify `xmax` and `ymax`, which clips the vectors away. This also explains the asymmetric behavior.

Comment: Oh thank you this is much more elegant, I'm not sure why its in terms of the xmax and ymax. I've never actually understood the difference between the domain and the two so perhaps I should read up on that.

Comment: @JohnMiller `xmax` will cut off at `x=xmax` regardless of the domain. Since you do not specify `xmin`, the result is asymmetric.